# MacOS command line xcrun gives 2 identical code signing identities

Tags: macos, code-signing, keychain

On MacOS Sonoma *(with XCode 15.0.1 installed)* when I run this code-signing command in the terminal I get 2 exactly identical entries:

> `xcrun security find-identity -v -p codesigning`

This causes problems with the XCode command-line signing utility.

What do I need to do to fix this duplicate identity problem?

When I open the Key-Chain app I only see one entry.